# Statistics of the ordering of columns

Tags: pandas, scipy, statsmodels

Say I have a dataframe with `N` columns (e.g. `N=3`). Every row represents a sample:

```
                A        B        C                                
sample_1       64       46       69
sample_2       55       33       40
sample_3       67       51       78
sample_4       97       32       62
sample_5       50       36       39
```

I would like to know what is the **most common ordering** of the columns `A`, `B`, `C` across rows.

In the case above, one could sort every row manually:

```
sample_1: [B, A, C]
sample_2: [B, C, A] 
sample_3: [B, A, C]
sample_4: [B, C, A] 
sample_5: [B, C, A]
```

and then find out that the most common ordering is `[B, C, A]`, while `[B, A, C]` is the second most common.

Are there any functions in Pandas, scipy or statsmodels that facilitate this analysis? For example, what if I want to find out **how often** each ordering happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> f = lambda ts: df.columns[np.argsort(ts).values]
>>> Counter(map(tuple, df.apply(f, axis=1).values))
Counter({('B', 'C', 'A'): 3, ('B', 'A', 'C'): 2})
```

So the most common ordering is:

```
>>> _.most_common(1)
[(('B', 'C', 'A'), 3)]
```

Alternatively:

```
>>> f = lambda ts: tuple(df.columns[np.argsort(ts)])
>>> df.apply(f, axis=1, raw=True).value_counts()
(B, C, A)    3
(B, A, C)    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks, but with the first approach I get: `IndexError: (unsupported iterator index', 'ocurred at index sample_1')` (latest stable Pandas on Python 3.x). The error specifically is with `df.apply(f, axis=1)` with `f` as it is defined). I tried it with `pd.read_clipboard()` from the OP.

Comment: @user815423426 how about the alternative solution?

Comment: @user815423426 also, try `np.argsort(ts).values`, instead of `np.argsort(ts)`

Comment: Your last suggestion (adding `.values`) did it

Comment: @user815423426 surprisingly it works for me without `.values`

Comment: I wonder if one can take it a step further and infer a distribution on the ordering (perhaps Dirichlet Distribution for each column on the most likely position for the column?). Any thoughts if there are distributions on orderings (or distances between consecutive elements)? I may check in CrossValidated (in case you are interested in the problem). Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 4):

It can be more efficient to use the cythonized `rank` function:

```
In [11]: df.rank(axis=1)
Out[11]:
          A  B  C
sample_1  2  1  3
sample_2  3  1  2
sample_3  2  1  3
sample_4  3  1  2
sample_5  3  1  2
```

You could then do a groupby, for example to get the sizes:

```
In [12]: df.rank(axis=1).groupby(['A', 'B', 'C']).size()
Out[12]:
A  B  C
2  1  3    2
3  1  2    3
dtype: int64
```

*Note: Here we're reading 2 1 3 to mean ["B", "A", "C"], however you could replace the index of the result as desired (i.e. replace it with one of these):*

```
In [13]: res.index.map(lambda y: ["_ABC"[int(x)] for x in y])
Out[13]: array([['B', 'A', 'C'], ['C', 'A', 'B']], dtype=object)

In [14]: res.index.map(lambda y: "".join(["_ABC"[int(x)] for x in y]))
Out[14]: array(['BAC', 'CAB'], dtype=object)
```

---

Here's the performance for a slightly larger dataframe:

```
In [21]: df1 = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)

In [22]: %timeit df1.rank(axis=1).groupby(['A', 'B', 'C']).size()
100 loops, best of 3: 4.82 ms per loop

In [23]: %timeit Counter(map(tuple, df1.apply(f, axis=1).values))
1 loops, best of 3: 1.68 s per loop
```